# Simplest configuration for Emacs (OS X)

Tags: macos, emacs, configuration, osx-yosemite

I use Emacs everyday on my PC, running on Ubuntu... I use to run it directly on the terminal, with the "emacs -nw option".
I also have a mac, running on OS-X Yosemite, but I can't figure how to configure it.

On my Ubuntu, I do "M-i" to do some tabulations, and every shortcuts are working properly.

But on my mac, by default, the Alt key isn't set as the meta key. I can set the option "Alt key as virtual key" in the Terminal preferences, but if set this option, I can't write "braces" anymore because "Alt + (" writes now a some parenthesis.

I tried many times some options, some .emacs configurations found on the internet, but nothing worked. All I want, is my OS X Emacs working like an ordinary Linux emacs. I also tried AquaEmacs, but I can't run it from the terminal...
Could someone tell me a basic configuration, or maybe an other version of emacs ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: The emacs that I have on my mac has ESC key mapped to Meta. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, my ESC key is mapped to Meta to. But it's not convenient at all for the shortcuts...

Comment: Terminal.app has a *Preferences* option, which has a *Settings* tab, which has a *Keyboard* tab, which has a check-box "**Use option as meta key**".  Check that box.

Comment: That's what I did. But now I can't access the braces "}{" anymore...

Comment: Why can't you just type Shift+{ or Shift +} ?  The Apple keyboard in the U.S. has keys that the right pinky hits which looks like {[ and }]

Comment: I forgot to mention, as I'm french, I'm using an azerty keyboard !
So if I check the "Use option as meta key", shift + 5 or alt + 5 do the same.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with a French keyboard, but here is an example of what I do for special characters in foreign languages when running in a GUI version of Emacs:  `(defun insert-spanish-lowercase-a () (interactive) (insert "á")) (define-key global-map (kbd "M-a") 'insert-spanish-lowercase-a)`  I assume that the same concept would apply to inserting certain characters in the terminal, but I have never tried it.  Any recognized character should be able to be inserted -- e.g., braces.  The usage of `@username` causes stackoverflow to send a notification to the non-original poster of a new comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering back my own question as I found a solution.
My advice would be to use the ITerm terminal instead of the native OS X Terminal App.
Iterm allows more flexibility, and thus, more ways to configure meta keys.